# Proving that $\operatorname{Span}(u, v + lu) \subseteq \operatorname{Span}(u, v)$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-writing

Let $u, v$ be elements of a real vector space $V$, and let $l\in\mathbb R$.

a) Prove that $\operatorname{Span}(u, v + lu) \subseteq \operatorname{Span}(u, v)$.

b) Prove that $\operatorname{Span}(u, v) \subseteq \operatorname{Span}(u, v + lu)$?

I'm really struggling and not sure how to prove part a) and part b). Any answers or where to start? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: For the part $(b)$, notice that

$$au + bv = au + b(v +lu - lu) = (a-bl)u + b(v+lu)$$

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 2):

For part a), think about what a generic element $w \in$ span$(u, v + lu)$ looks like, just from the definition of spanning:

$w = c_1 u + c_2 (v + lu) \ \ \ (c_i \in \mathbb{R})$

Can you prove that this is also element of span$(u,v)$? If so, you've proven that span$(u,v+lu) \subseteq $ span$(u,v)$ (do you see why?).

Answer (score 1):

$Span(u,v+lu)$ is the set of all linear combinations of $u$ and $v+lu$,

thus all elements of the form $a \cdot u + b \cdot (v+lu)$ for $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$.

However, you can group together like terms: $(a+lb)\cdot u + b \cdot v$ and $a$ can be rewritten as $a= a’ -l$, and we get $ a’ \cdot u + b\cdot v$. (You can skip this step if you like, $a+lb$ is already a real number so technically we’d be done as soon as we brought together like terms, but it’s more for visuals).

So it turns out to be a linear combination of $u$ and $v$ also. $Span(u,v+lu) \subseteq Span(u,v)$.

Next, given $Span(u,v)$, all linear combinations of the form $a\cdot u + b\cdot v$ for $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ can be written as $(a-bl+bl)\cdot u + b\cdot v = (a-bl)\cdot u + bl\cdot u + b\cdot v = (a-bl)\cdot u + b\cdot(v+lu),$ because we are adding $0=bl-bl$ to the coefficient $a$. Now $a,b,l \in \mathbb{R}$ thus so is $a-bl$, and you have a linear combination of the form $a’ \cdot u + b\cdot (v+lu)$ for $a’,b \in \mathbb{R}$.
$Span(u,v) \subseteq Span(u,v+lu).$

Comment: When you said you can group together like terms isn't it (a+b)⋅ . Can I say (a+b) is a real number and therefore it is ⊆(,)?

Comment: Yup! Thanks for spotting the typo!